# Entity Framework TPC inheritance issue

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

I'd like to have Table Per Concrete type inheritance in my application:

```
public class Row {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ExtendedRow : Row {
    public int Weight {get;set;}
}
```

Each of the classes need to be mapped to their own view and `ExtendedRow` view has all the columns of `Row` view.

My configuration is:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Row>().Map(m => {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("Row");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<ExtendedRow >().Map(m => {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("ExtendedRow");
    });
```

Querying `ExtendedRow` is just fine. However, querying `Row` generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Row] AS [Extent1]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[ExtendedRow] AS [Extent2]
```

Why does EF add `UNION ALL` operator? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596289/table-per-concrete-type-tpc-inheritance-in-entity-framework-6-ef6?rq=1) that worked for me:

```
public abstract class RowBase {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Row : RowBase {
}

public class ExtendedRow : RowBase {
    public int Weight {get;set;}
}
```

The key is to have an `abstract` class so that EF do not try to use inheritance logic if `MapInheritedProperties()` is used.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues on stack overflow about this topic.
EF works in the way you see, if you ask for Base you will receive all objects that implements Base (i.e. Base and derived objects). If you use TPC you will see UNION, if you use TPH you will see that EF omits the where clause on the discriminator field (i.e. it does not matter TPC or TPH, the result is always the same).
`GetType` is not an EF canonical function so you can't use it but I've read that with EF 6.x you can use is (in your case `!(m is ExtendedRow)`). Actually I don't know if it works.

Usually I don't map Base class (i.e. I make an empty class that derive from base than I map it).